# how to filter the calendar view based on name of manager

Tags: sharepoint-calendar

I have an online SharePoint calendar that shows all the employees who request/or took leave. When they request for leave they need approval from their line manager.

My question is: how can the manager view the calendar showing only the employees working under him as different employees have different managers?

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 ways of doing it out of the box.

1. Create a view for each manager with the filter against employees. (where employe -eq employee1 or employee -eq employee 2, instead of employee you might use created By column)

   - that approach can be quite time consuming if the company is very large
2. Add new column to the calendar called 'Manager' which employees would have to fill in. Then you can create more generic views like My Employees with filter 'Manager -eq [ME]'

Answer (score 0):

You can use Manager eq to [Me] condition in your view.

[image: View Condition]